# Wake on LAN directly via Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, wake-on-lan

I want to use wake on lan with my LG TV but it is only supported via cable connection. Is it possible to connect small computer (Orange Pi) directly to the TV via cable and send Wake packets directly?

Answer (score 3):

Look for [`wakeonlan`](https://github.com/jpoliv/wakeonlan) or `etherwake`, which are probably available in whatever distribution you’re using. You can then wake the TV up by specifying its MAC address:

```
wakeonlan 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

or

```
etherwake 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

(You’ll need to run `etherwake` as root; `wakeonlan` can be run as a regular user.)

You might want to look into HDMI CEC as an alternative to wake your TV up, over an HDMI connection rather than an Ethernet connection. The Raspberry Pi supports this, see [this page](https://elinux.org/CEC_(Consumer_Electronics_Control)_over_HDMI) for details; your distribution probably has [`libcec`](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec) too, along with the Python bindings (`python-libcec`). I don’t know whether the Orange Pi supports CEC (apparently it does), and more importantly whether any available software supports CEC on the Orange Pi (see [here](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=647&extra=&page=4)).

Answer (score 2):

I found the below link about Raspberry Pi, but the same applies to Orange Pi also.

You'll have to use the following command to install WOL:

```
sudo apt-get install etherwake
```

and you can wake your machine with

```
etherwake -i eth0 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

where AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF is target Ethernet address.

https://notenoughtech.com/featured/use-raspberry-pi-wol/

Comment: Another package is [wakeonlan](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/wakeonlan) (which I prefer as it doesn't require root).